# Component nesting in react with ES6 syntax

Tags: html, reactjs

When working on a name card generator app, trying to extract information from **address** object (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users). Was told the best way to present the text is to put them in separate components,  and . Now I am having troubles piecing the two components together. The code is down below.
(**Complete set of new code will be appreciated!**)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
const Namecard = ({ name, email, address }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{name}</p>
      <p>{email}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const Address = ({ street }) => {
  return <h1>{street}</h1>;
};

function App() {
  const [identis, setIdenti] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getIdenti();
  }, []);

  const getIdenti = async () => {
    const acquired = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
    const data = await acquired.json();
    setIdenti(data);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {identis.map(identi => (
        <Namecard name={identi.name} email={identi.email}>
          <Address street={identi.address.city} />
        </Namecard>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So with the current code, the output only includes name and email. Nothing is shown from the address object.

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Answer (score 2):

`Namecard` needs to explicitly render its children, otherwise they are not rendered:

```
const Namecard = ({name,email,children}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{name}</p>
            <p>{email}</p>
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use **Address** component as a children of **Namecard** component, so you should tell **Namecard** component that use this children component and render in his body.

For example you could rewrite **Namecard** component like that:

```js
const Namecard = ({name, email, address, children}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{name}</p>
            <p>{email}</p>
            {children}
        </div>
    )
};
```

and as a children our component render `<Address street={identi.address.city}/>`

Or you could rewrite like that: render **Address** component inside **Namecard**:

```js
const Namecard = ({name, email, address}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{name}</p>
            <p>{email}</p>
            <Address street={address.city}/>
        </div>
    )
};

const Address = ({street}) => <h1>{street}</h1>;

function App() {
    const [identis, setIdenti] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
            getIdenti();
        }, []
    );

    const getIdenti = async () => {
        const acquired = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
        const data = await acquired.json();
        setIdenti(data);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {identis.map(identi => (
                <Namecard
                    name={identi.name}
                    email={identi.email}
                    address={identi.address}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```